# Dúvidas sobre Markup Validation errors W3C

Tags: php, validação, html-tags

Este validator não traz nenhuma informação de que lugar poderia ser para arrumá-lo.
Sei que tem o Line 233, Column 10, mas pode ser de qualquer lugar.

Existe algum método ou alguma coisa para saber como eu descubro em qual arquivo está o problema?
Já tentei procurar pelo meu programa de php, mas são muitos arquivos pra procurar 1 a 1, (uso joomla)

> Line 250, Column 9: end tag for "td" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
>               "`</tr`"
>
> You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "`/>`" instead of "`>`".

Comment: Ao que parece, uma tag de célula não foi fechada corretamente.
    `<td>...</td>` Tá pedindo o `</td>`, inspecione o código e veja se não existe alguma célula de alguma tabela nesta linha, que esteja mal finalizada, ou até com algum escape, fazendo virar texto.

Comment: Ta ali oh, vc não colocou o ">" no "<tr />".

Answer (score 3):

O validador não tem acesso aos seus arquivos PHP, só ao HTML que ele gera. O erro está na linha 233 desse HTML. Olhe o trecho de HTML dessa linha e procure (manualmente) o PHP que gera esse trecho.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica. Vai levar bastante tempo, mas irei verificar manualmente.